# 中にも meaning and translation

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation

I came across a passage in my text book that reads, 「私は科学的に正しいと考えられていることの中にも正しくないことはあると思う」
For my 中に has two means which both don’t really fit this sentence. Inside and out of (something).
Could some one explain this sentence and maybe this proper meaning of 中にも.
Feel free to use examples!

Thankyou.

Comment: 1) This sentence is ungrammatical. 私は has no corresponding predicate. Perhaps a verb like 思います is missing. Please ensure you have copied it correctly. 2) Please add your translation attempt. Otherwise people would have to explain every single aspect of this complex sentence.

Comment: Sorry! I corrected it so please explain if possible.

Comment: Please add your best translation attempt. It's tough to explain this sentence when I don't even know whether you know about relative clauses.

Comment: “There are things thought to be scientifically correct that I disagree with” would be my translation. But Iv never seen 中に used this way!

Answer (score 5):

This ～の中に means "in ～", "inside ～", "among ～" or "within ～". 中 by itself is a noun that means "interior", "middle", "content", etc. It can be used with a group (of people, objects, ideas, etc), too.

> 箱の中にボールがある。
>   There is a ball inside the box.
>
> 私たちの中に殺人者がいる。
>   There is a murderer among us.

I suppose this is easy for you, but this sentence has several nested clauses, which seems to have confused you. Let's start from a simple sentence.

> Aの中にBがある。
>   There is B within A.

> Aの中に**も**B**は**ある。
>   B exists **also/even** within A.
>   <sub>も = even/also, は = topic/contrast marker</sub>

Where A is:

> 科学的に正しいと考えられている**こと**
>   **things** that are considered as scientifically correct

And B is:

> 正しくない**こと**
>   **things** that are incorrect

Finally, these are enclosed by 私は～と思う using quotative-と:

> **私は**「(科学的に正しいと考えられていること)の中にも(正しくないこと)はある」**と思う**。
>   **I think that** there are incorrect things even among things that are considered as scientifically true.